# JSON Type Validation - Guidance

Tags: python, json, validation, etl, jsonschema

I have a stream of events coming in as JSON.  The schema for the JSON is well defined, but the source producing them doesn't always behave when it comes to types.

**Example Schema**:

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "properties":{
        "FirstName": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/FirstName",
            "required":false
        },
        "MiddleName": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/MiddleName",
            "required":false
        },
        "LastName": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/LastName",
            "required":false
        },
        "Age": {
            "type":"number",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Age",
            "required":false
        }
}
```

In some cases the `Age` shows up as a "-" character, meaning it was left blank when the record was created.  Obviously this isn't a number, thus my problem.

I'm not using any formal JSON validation library, but I was considering looping through each element of the event and handling any needed type conversation.  In the example above, I would just make age `0`.

Is there a way to validate each element and then apply some type of conversation function is it fails validation?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Schematics](https://github.com/schematics/schematics) with custom Types to do this.  Works perfectly.